# How to get a database on my filesystem that I can use in my application

Tags: c#, .net, database

I'm making a .NET application where I'll have a lot of data entries. This will not go to any server though, but needs to be stored and updated, frequently on the local machine.

I would like something like an SQL database, that simply exists in a file, in my application's folder (or in %appdata% or whatever).

But how do I go about this? What can I use? I'm a big fan of Linq2Sql, so if it supports that, it would be awesome.

I've tried to use MSSQL Compact, but I couldn't really get it to work very well. It basically required me to install MSSQL as well.

What options do I have, other than MSSQL Compact?

Comment: You could go with LocalDB, see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780941/sql-server-localdb-v11-0-explained).

Comment: product or service recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic]. see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: Try [Software Recommendations beta](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept you're talking about is generally referred to as an [embedded database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database) (or sometimes, a serverless database).

There are many out there; I don't think lists are a good format for this site, but you could try [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html), for example.  If you need a more fully-fledged RDBMS, something like Firebird embedded might be appropriate.